# Converting a first norm into a linear program

Tags: normed-spaces, linear-programming

I want to convert the following problem into a linear program. 
$$ \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \qquad \lvert\lvert Ax - b \rvert\rvert_1$$

Here $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$

This was my train of thought so far:

By definition, the first norm is,

$$ \lvert \lvert y\rvert \rvert_1 = \lvert y_1\rvert + \lvert y_2 \rvert + ...+ \lvert y_n\rvert$$
Now I know that an absolute value can be represented by replacing the variable with two non-negative variables. But I know it only for a single variable:
$$ \lvert x \rvert = x^+ - x^- $$
I have no idea how to do this when the expression is in the format $\lvert a_i^Tx - b_i\rvert$ where $a_i^T$ is a row of the matrix $A$. (Yes I am dumb, I know it).

The best I could think of is adding a constraint $y = Ax -b$ and using $y$ as my variable:

\begin{align}
\min_{y_i^+, y_i^- \in \mathbb{R}}  \quad & y_1^+ + y_1^- + y_2^+ + y_2^- + y_3^+ + y_3^-+ \dots + y_m^+ + y_m^-\\
s.t.  \quad & a_1^Tx - b_1 = y_1^+ - y_1^- \\
            & a_2^Tx - b_2 = y_2^+ - y_2^- \\
            & a_3^Tx - b_3 = y_3^+ - y_3^- \\
                        \vdots
              & a_m^Tx - b_m = y_m^+ - y_m^-
\end{align}

This is all I can think. Is this the right way to go? Is there anything missing? Or is this entirely wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine. Don't forget to include the nonnegative constraints for your $y_i^+$ and $y_i^-$.

Alternatively

$$\min \sum_{i=m}^n z_i$$

$$z_i \ge a_i^Tx-b_i$$

$$z_i \ge -(a_i^Tx-b_i)$$

$\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$.